# Mathematics Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 10 BALLS and 3 boxes, how many possible number of solutions are there with a maximum number of 9 and minimum number of 1? numbers cannot be repeated.

Mathematically, we are finding the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=10$ where $1\leq x_1,x_2,x_3\leq9$ and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are integers.

Comment: 2,5,3? Those add up to ten and match your condition. Forgive me if I didnt understand your question right.

Comment: Never Mind. What we actually need is the number of possibilities that adds up to 10.

Comment: I guess [7,2,1] and [6,1,3] also work, not much combinations to work with

Answer (score 1):

Straight enumeration is the way to go here, but you can simplify a little I think.    Since you don't allow repeats, this is the same as $6$ times the number of ways to write $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$ with $x_i$ strictly increasing and greater than or equal to $1$.  Subtracting $i$ from $x_i$, we see that's the same as counting the number of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4$ with the $x_i$ weakly increasing and greater than $0$.  It's pretty quick to enumerate these, there are only $4$ of them, $(0,0,4),(0,1,3),(0,2,2),(1,1,2)$.  So, there are $24$ ways to allocate the balls in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assume for the moment that we want $x_1<x_2<x_3$. The we necessarily have
$$\eqalign{x_1&=1+y_1,\cr x_2&=(x_1+1)+y_2=2+y_1+y_2,\cr x_3&=(x_2+1)+y_3=3+y_1+y_2+y_3\cr}$$
with $y_k\geq0$ $\>(1\leq k\leq 3)$. The condition $x_1+x_2+x_3=10$ then implies
$$3y_1+2y_2+y_3=4\ ,\tag{1}$$ which automatically enforces $y_1+y_2+y_3\leq 6$, or $x_3\leq9$.

The nonnegative solutions of $(1)$ can be found by inspection: We obtain the triples $(0,0,4)$, $(0,1,2)$ and $(0,2,0)$ with $y_1=0$ and the single triple $(1,0,1)$ with $y_1=1$.

So there are $4$ solutions when the $x_k$ are in increasing order, or $24$ solutions when they can be in any order.

Answer (score -3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
?&=\sum_{x_{1} = 1}^{9}\sum_{x_{2} = 1}^{9}\sum_{x_{3} = 1}^{9}
\delta_{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}, 10}
=\sum_{x_{1} = 1}^{9}\sum_{x_{2} = 1}^{9}\sum_{x_{3} = 1}^{9}\int_{\verts{z} = 1}
{1 \over z^{11 - x_{1} - x_{2} - x_{3}}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}\pars{\sum_{x = 1}^{9}z^{x}}^{3}{1 \over z^{11}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}\bracks{z\pars{z^{9} - 1} \over z - 1}^{3}{1 \over z^{11}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 - z^{9}}^{3} \over \pars{1 - z}^{3}}{1 \over z^{8}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{3}{3 \choose \ell}
\pars{-z^{9}}^{\ell}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}{\ell' + 2 \choose 2}z^{\ell'}\,
{1 \over z^{8}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{3}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{\ell}{3 \choose \ell}
{\ell' + 2 \choose 2}\delta_{9\ell + \ell',7}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{3}\pars{-1}^{\ell}{3 \choose \ell}
\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\infty}{\ell' + 2 \choose 2}\delta_{\ell',7 - 9\ell}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{\ell\ =\ 0 \atop {\vphantom{\LARGE A}\ell\ \leq\ 7/9}}^{3}\pars{-1}^{\ell}
{3 \choose \ell}{9 - 9\ell \choose 2} = {9 \choose 2} = \color{#0000ff}{\Large 36}
\end{align}